# Change TTS Engine programatically (MAUI)

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, maui, text-to-speech

I am writing a simple application in MAUI .NET that will use Text-To-Speech. I notice that on Samsung smartphones by default there is a ,,Samsung text-to-speech engine''.

I need to use ,,Speech Services by Google''. Is there any option to change it programmatically in .net?

```
 SpeechOptions options = new SpeechOptions()
    {
        Pitch = 1.5f, 
        Volume = 0.75f,
        Locale = locales.Where(a => a.Country == "PL").FirstOrDefault()
    };

    await TextToSpeech.Default.SpeakAsync(textToSpeech, options);
```